# Find the 5 missing ratios in $\tan \theta=\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{8}$, and $\cos < 0$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

I was working through this question: find the 5 missing ratios in $\tan \theta=\frac{7\sqrt{2}}{8}, and \cos<0.$
I thought I had found a shortcut where I could use trig identities in order to find $\sin\theta$ and $\cos\theta$ given the identity $\tan\theta = \frac{\sin\theta}{\cos\theta}$, meaning that $\sin\theta=7\sqrt{2}$ and $\cos\theta = 8$. Obviously, this is not the case given that the range of $\sin\theta = [-1,1]$. Why is this the case? Where did my thinking fall apart?

Comment: You can draw a right triangle to find the sine and cosine you mention as the y, x coordinates respectively.   There will be two possibilities. The fact that cosine is negative limits you to one possibility. From there, solve the right triangle and you can calculate every trigonometric value.

Comment: Complex system hain why sin theta should be in -1/to 1.

Comment: Tangent is a ratio. $\frac{9}{36}=\frac{1}{4}$ but $9 \ne 1$ and $36 \ne 4$. However, you can use the similarity of triangles, draw a triangle with legs $7\sqrt 2$ and $8$ and calculate sines and cosines.

Comment: @skrek: If I tell you that I'm thinking of two numbers whose ratio is $3/4$, *you can't be sure* that those numbers are $3$ and $4$. Maybe they're $6$ and $8$. Or $\sqrt{18}$ and $\sqrt{32}$. Or $3\pi$ and $4\pi$. Or any of *infinitely-many* other pairs. However, if I also tell you that the sum of the squares of those numbers is $1$ (and, for simplicity, that they're positive), then you can deduce with certainty that my numbers are $3/5$ and $4/5$. ... So it is with sine and cosine. The identity $\tan x=\sin x/\cos x$ isn't enough to specify them; you also need $\sin^2x+\cos^2x=1$.

Comment: In @Vasili 's comment it's hinted that you should write $$\tan\theta=\frac{a\sin\theta}{a\cos\theta},$$where $a$ is just a real number. Then use $a\sin\theta=7\sqrt 2$. To get the value of $a$, $\sin^2\theta+\cos^2\theta=1$,

Comment: $\cos(?) = 0$.  It's senseless to add "$\cos =0$".

Answer (score 1):

What you’re missing is the length of the hypothenuse and the fact that sine and cosine are both negative. The tangent is giving you the ratio of the legs corresponding to the principal angle, as in $$\tan\theta\gt 0\Rightarrow\tan\theta=\tan\theta_0=\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{adjacent}}=\frac{\frac{\text{opposite}}{\text{hypothenuse}}}{\frac{\text{adjacent}}{\text{hupothenuse}}}, \theta_0 \text{ principal angle}$$

You can’t say “$\sin \theta=7\sqrt 2$”, because since $\tan\theta\gt0, \cos\theta\lt0\Rightarrow \sin\theta\lt0$.

You could say “$\sin\theta=-\frac{7\sqrt 2}{\text{hypothenuse}}\Rightarrow\sin\theta_0=\frac{7\sqrt 2}{\text{hypothenuse}}$”

To determine h, the length of hypothenuse use the fundamental identity of trigonometry:$$\sin^2x+cos^2x=1\Leftrightarrow \left(\frac{7\sqrt 2}{h}\right)^2+\left(\frac{8}{h}\right)^2=1\Rightarrow h=\sqrt{(7\sqrt2)^2+8^2}$$

You could now determine the principal angle: $$\sin\theta_0=\frac{7\sqrt 2}{\sqrt{(7\sqrt 2)^2+8^2}}, \theta_0 \text{ being the principal angle}$$

Since $\cos\theta\lt 0, \tan\theta\gt 0\Rightarrow \theta=\pi+\theta_0$

The angle $\theta$ with principal angle $\theta_0$ terminates in quadrant 3, where $\sin \le0, \cos \le 0, \tan\ge 0, \cot \ge 0, \sec \lt 0, \csc\lt 0$.

Comment: If $\tan\theta > 0$ and $\cos\theta < 0$, what can you conclude about $\sin\theta$?

Answer (score 1):

You have not taken the radius of the circle into account or the sign of the coordinates into account.

If an angle has vertex at the origin, initial side along the positive $x$-axis, and the terminal side of the angle passes through point $(x, y)$, then
\begin{align*}
\sin\theta & = \frac{y}{r} & \csc\theta & = \frac{r}{y}\\[2mm]
\cos\theta & = \frac{x}{r} & \sec\theta & = \frac{r}{x}\\[2mm]
\tan\theta & = \frac{y}{x} & \cot\theta & = \frac{x}{y}
\end{align*}
where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$ is the radius of the circle with center at the origin on which the point $(x, y)$ lies.

Keep in mind that the equations $\sin\theta = y$ and $\cos\theta = x$ only apply when $r = 1$.

Notice that if $\tan\theta > 0$ and $\cos\theta < 0$, then $\sin\theta = \tan\theta\cos\theta < 0$.  Since $\cos\theta < 0$ and $\sin\theta < 0$, $\theta$ must be a third-quadrant angle.

$$\tan\theta = \frac{y}{x} = \frac{7\sqrt{2}}{8} = \frac{-7\sqrt{2}}{-8}$$

Hence, we can take $(x, y) = (-8, -7\sqrt{2})$.  The point $(-8, -7\sqrt{2})$ lies on a circle of radius $r$, where
$$r = \sqrt{(-8)^2 + (-7\sqrt{2})^2} = \sqrt{64 + 98} = \sqrt{162} = \sqrt{81} \sqrt{2} = 9\sqrt{2}$$
Since we now know the values of $x$, $y$, and $r$, you can use the above formulas to compute $\sin\theta$, $\cos\theta$, $\csc\theta$, $\sec\theta$, and $\cot\theta$.

Comment: Closely agree with this answer (+1). @shrek Although not stated explicitly, when dealing with solutions to trigonometric functions, always refer back to the [unit circle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle) to ensure no solutions are missed/omitted.